# Transact SQL- Calculate leave days in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the number of leave days taken for staff in the financial year (1 July 2017 to 30 June 2018).

Some staff apply for leave outside these days and it overlaps for example a staff member may have a leave application of -start date of 30/06/2017 to 03/07/2017, so that is 2 days, but I would need to capture just the 1 day in July 2017.

I just want to be 100% here, so here is my query below

```
Select * from leave where leave_start < '2018-07-01' and leave_end > '2017-06-30'
```

The table is

```
Staffno | leave_type | leave_start | leave_end  | days_taken
0001    | AnnualLeave| 30/06/2017  | 03/07/2018 |    2
```

Obviously once I get the result I will need to work out the actual start and actual end date and then do a networkdays formula in excel for it.

Thanks, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a table that might contain information relevant to this question?  If so, the question should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please also show your existing query

Comment: No worries, I've edited my post with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement to substitute boundary dates if start and end dates are out of interval. In your example you don't count start and end date as a leave so if you need this in the query (here start and end days are counted as a leave) just add "-2" into `period_days_taken` definition:

```
Select leave.*, 
       DATEDIFF(DAY,
               CASE WHEN leave_start<'2017-06-30' 
                    THEN '2017-06-30' 
                    ELSE leave_start END,
               CASE WHEN leave_end>'2018-07-01' 
                    THEN '2018-07-01' 
                    ELSE leave_end END) 

       AS  period_days_taken

from leave 

WHERE leave_start <= '2018-07-01' 
      AND leave_end >= '2017-06-30'
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45e76/1)</kbd>